# CSS - Logo acting different with Chrome / Safari

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, safari

My logo acts weird in Safari, and on my iPad's Chrome/Safari.

The issue is that **the height is different**, and it become squeezed on Safari / iPad.

I really don't know how to track issues with Safari, and would love both an direct answer or some guiding.

I mainly use Chrome, and if you have any tips for issue tracking trouble with Safari - it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks alot! =)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You need to insert the code to reproduce your issue in the question itself. You should also take a look at this : [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Making people go to an offline ressource to understand your question isn't good practice + when your site goes offline or is changed, this question will become worthless.

Comment: Please avoid posting sensitive credentials on public forums.

Comment: Put more mind into your editing rvenius. This was not sensitive credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to invest the issue by using the Element Inspector from Safari.

When clicking the Logo, you'll see both the HTML and CSS. When disabling a few CSS properties, which is a regular cause of insecurities, I found that disabling the following style fixes your problem:

Rule #296 of Layout.css

```
#Top_bar #logo img { vertical-align: middle; /* max-height: 100%; */ }
```

The Max-height was your trouble maker.

Also, a little personal taste: Avoid resizing images in the browser. It'll lack performance and visual quality.

The logo is good looking, but it gets blurred while resized.

Comment: Great insight! Thanks alot Lars, you're awesome! :D

Comment: Anytime Frikk ^^ Also, don't forget to mark it as the answer if it was the solution to your problem ^^